# "Заместить на" — корректно ли?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

Участник Галактион задал целый ряд вопросов о "замещении на", и никто его не поправил.  В Нацкопрусе есть несколько примеров, все из области химии. Это профессиональный сленг?

> С точки зрения химика-синтетика, подобные соединения представляют собой как бы «недосинтезированные» вещества, иными словами, не все силанолятные группы в процессе обменной реакции **замещены на** поливалентный металл. [Михаил Левицкий. Металлоорганосилоксаны и литосфера // «Российский химический журнал», 2002]

Но у Кузнецова даже в химии нет **замещения** **на**:

> Реакция замещения. Хим. Химическое превращение, при котором в молекуле соединения атомы одного элемента **замещают атомы** другого элемента. ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Answer (score 2):

Если это не является общепринятым жаргонизмом в химии (чаще всего "заместить" встречается в них с прямым дополнением), то правильно "**заместить тем-то**" (буквально: **занять его место тем-то**) или (в обычных текстах без реакций замещения) "*заменить на*".

Comment: Спасибо! Получив поддержку с Вашей стороны, я убрал слова "замещение на" из заголовков старых вопросов.